Create an externaly hosted SFMC Custom App with dynamic credentials
I've created a custom SFMC app that allow to create complex forms with field dependencies and post-validation actions.
This app was build completly with CloudPages and SSJS/Ampscript code.
Now I want to rewrite it into an externaly hosted app that I can easily install on any SFMC org.
I'm using this git repo as a base :
https://github.com/invokecreate/example-sfmc-app
However there is one part of the app that I'm not sure about: How to make it universal, without any credentials hard-coded ? For example I wan't to be able to install it for client A, but also for client B, with the same app, so the same URL.
The only way I see to do that would be to store the credentials (clientId, clientSecret, baseUrl..) in an external database, but I find it weird that their isn't another way.
Here is how it would work:
The app is installed on the client's SFMC instance, by creating an Installed Package with a "Marketing Cloud App" component and a Web App API Integration component.
When the app is loaded for the first time, it detects that it doesn't have the API Integration credentials for this instance, so it asks the user to enter them. When the user validate the form, it stores the credentials in an external database.
That way when the app is loaded later it can go fetch the credentials without having to ask them again.
The database would be able to store as many credentials as we want, so that we can install and use the app on different instances.
This seems the be feasable, I'm just not sure how I would know wich credentials I need to use for which instance (maybe I can use the referer of the iframe ?).
Is there another way ? I'm wondering how the apps on the App Excvhange works.
For example Query Studio, you just instal it and you don't have to setup anything. Maybe there is a way to automaticaly link the API Integration credentials to the Marketing Cloud App ?
Thanks,
Thomas

I would typically see the credentials in environment variables in your app, so heroku, cloudflare etc.
Meaning they would not be hardcoded inside the app, but you'd host one version for each customer, enter credentials on the hosting side, and that's it.
This would of course result in not the same URL used across systems, but it would be separate installations that are easily copied (which I think gets to your point of quick reusability).
What you suggest sounds "almost" feasible, but I would very much doubt it before I see it.  The issue I see is that the iframe injection just gets you an authcode at first.  Only with the authcode, you can trade the credentials in a second step, for a token. And only AFTER you have the token, you can extract the accountId context from the token.
What you describe is: You want the account ID at the start;
What I describe it: you get it at the end
here I described my pains with it, but I got the stuff I describe to work eventually -  Custom Content Block / triggerAuth2 workflow
== At any rate:
IF you get it to work (one central app running for however enters login data) - I doubt I would like to set that up and live with it as an SF partner. I would very much want separate installations.

Given that you will pay for the hosting, you'd be paying for the hosting based on usage, but usage would be split among customers, so you'd have to set up contractual terms around misuse etc. - ugly. One app per customer means clear attribution.

same for load. imagine customer A manages to take down the app, all others would suffer; Then you are in SAAS hell - likely without being a corporation that has the resources for it.

ownership; you couldn't transfer ownership over a shared app; imagine a customer wants to make customizations themselves, how?

availability / maintenance hell. Imagine a customer wants YOU to make customizations, you mess it up, all customers suffer, but just one eventually gets the intended benefit. I wouldnt want to explain that.


